# Create a SQL query using WP_Query or $wpdb variable

Tags: sql, wordpress, posts

I've to create the following query to take all posts ordered according to a specific hierarchy using WP_query or $wpdb:

```
select *
from postTable
where tag = 'tag1'
order by category, tag2, date
union
select *
from nometabella
where tag <> 'tag1'
order by category, 'tag2', date
```

where `tag1` and `tag2` are tags. In this way, the posts are shown in a specific order

`(first posts with tag1 grouped by category, tag2 and date, then posts grouped by category and, for each category, they are grouped by tag2 and date)`.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: What is this _'data'_ you are referring to? Is it the `post_content`/maintext?

Comment: date, I'm sorry..

Comment: It's gonna be tough but might be possible. As [orderby](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) takes an array for multiple order. But probably you will need too do multiple calls. Or sort after fetching all posts.